# active tab text color change

Tags: html, css, tabs

```html
<div class="tabs-tending">
               <div class="tabs-tending-2">
                <label for="tabs-tending-1"class="ten-mhead">TRENDING <span>|<span></label>
                 <input id="tabs-tending-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
                   <div>
                 <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-tending-2">
    <label for="tabs-tending-2" class="fav-mhead">FAVOURITES</label>
    <input id="tabs-tending-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
    <div>
       <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a two tab list with inner tab content, here is both tabs text same color when switch, but I need active tab text color change that will be black and inactive tab text color will be grey, I have tried in css but not working looking same when switching, here is added html & css, please check. Thanks in advance

```css
.tabs-tending {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] label,
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
   /*  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5); */
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
    -moz-appearance: media-slider;
    appearance: media-slider;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, 
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
      /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc20e; */}
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
      /* border-bottom: 2px solid #009297; */ }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      opacity: 1; }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 0rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 {
    width: 50%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 [type="radio"] + div {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: 200%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
      margin-left: 100%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: -100%; }
```

Comment: can't find nay working snippet

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time, much appreciated!... here is lengthy html code that why I didn't  added, could you please check in css code

Comment: on tab click what class is added by library in `tab`

Comment: this class .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: center;

Comment: show your complete tabs html

Comment: I have updated html code

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your styles to your class names it should work.

> - When used together with the  element, the for attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

Per: [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp)

This can be done using simple CSS.

```css
.ten-mhead, .fav-mhead {
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ten-mhead:active, .fav-mhead:active {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label for="tabs-tending-1"class="ten-mhead">tab 1</label>
<label for="tabs-tending-2" class="fav-mhead">tab 2</label>
```

**EDIT:** Is this the behavior you're looking for?

```css
label {
  color: grey;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6.5rem;
}

.tabs-tending {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-tending">
   <div class="tabs-tending-2">
      <input class="checked" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
      <label class="ten-mhead">TRENDING |</label>
      <div>
         <p>content</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabs-tending-2">
      <input class="checked" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
      <label class="fav-mhead">FAVORITES |</label>
      <div>
         <p>content</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your precious time, much appreciated! I need tab function which one is active with black color, not on hover

Comment: @Designer16 See edits. This what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tabs-tending {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] label,
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
  .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
   /*  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5); */
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
    -moz-appearance: media-slider;
    appearance: media-slider;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, 
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
      /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc20e; */}
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
      /* border-bottom: 2px solid #009297; */ }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      opacity: 1; }
    .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 0rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 {
    width: 50%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 [type="radio"] + div {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: 200%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
      margin-left: 100%; }
    .tabs-tending .tabs-tending-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: -100%; }
      
      .tabs-tending [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
    .tabs-tending [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
      color: red }
```

```html
<div class="tabs-tending">
               <div class="tabs-tending-2">
                 <input id="tabs-tending-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
                 <label for="tabs-tending-1"class="ten-mhead">TRENDING <span>|<span></label>
                   <div>
                 <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-tending-2">
    <input id="tabs-tending-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
    <label for="tabs-tending-2" class="fav-mhead">FAVOURITES</label>
    <div>
       <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your given time, after this code apply tab function not working